# Querying one to many relationship which has two foreign keys using LINQ to Entities in MVC4

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, model-view-controller, reporting-services

I am new to C# and MVC and was currently introduced to Dependency Injection in order to control data to controller in a easier way. I am having a hard time to design my data table.

What I ideally would like to get is the below structure of data: 
Based on selected ClientID, Client can have one or more Parent Report and Parent Report could have one or more Child Report that contains URL and other informations.

Client ID

```
* Parent Report 1

    * Child Report 1.1


        * URL
    * Child Report 2.1

        * URL 
    * Child Report 3.1

        * URL 
* Parent Report 2

    * Child Report 2.1

        * URL
    * Child Report 2.2

        * URL 
    * Child Report 2.3

        * URL
```

[image]

As you can see I have two entity keys. To the first table, I will pass only client ID and I will be able to get all the parents reports and its child reports.

This is how I am implementing it:

Parent Report Model class:

```
{
    public class TableauParentReportModel
    {
        public int ClientId { get; set; }
        public int ParentReportId { get; set; }
        public string ParentReportName { get; set; }


        public List<TableauChildReportModel> TableauChildReports { get; set; }


}
```

ChildReport Model Class:

```
 public class TableauChildReportModel
    {

        public int ChildReportId { get; set; }
        public string ChildReportName { get; set; }
        public string ChildReportHashName { get; set; }
        public string ChildReportURL { get; set; }
        public int ParentReportId { get; set; }
        public int ClientId { get; set; }

    }
```

Here is my interface:

```
public interface ITableauReportingService

    {

        TableauParentReportModel GetTableauChildReportModel(int ParentReportId, int ClientId);
        IList<TableauParentReportModel> GetClientTableauReport(int ClientID);
        void CreateTableauReporting(TableauParentReportModel model);
        void Delete(int ParentReportId, int ClientId);





    }
```

Here is my service data:

1) TO get Child Reports:

```
public TableauParentReportModel GetTableauChildReportModel(int ParentReportId, int ClientId)
    {
        using (var connection = new TableauReportingEntitiesContainer())
        {
            var query = (from c in connection.TableauParentReports.Include("TableauChildReports")

                         where
                         c.ClientId == ClientId && c.ParentReportId == ParentReportId
                         select new TableauParentReportModel()
                         {
                             ClientId = c.ClientId,
                             ParentReportId = c.ParentReportId,
                             ParentReportName = c.ParentReportName,
                             TableauChildReports = (from t in c.TableauChildReports
                                                    select new TableauChildReportModel()
                                                    {


                                                        ChildReportId = t.ChildReportId,
                                                        ChildReportName = t.ChildReportName,
                                                        ChildReportHashName = t.ChildReportHashName,
                                                        ParentReportId = t.ParentReportId,
                                                        ClientId = t.ClientId


                                                    }).ToList()


                         }).First();

            return query;           


                       }

            throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

2) But I am having a trouble to get all Parent Reports and its child report of clients?

```
public IList<TableauParentReportModel> GetClientTableauReport(int ClientID)
{

    using (var connection = new TableauReportingEntitiesContainer())
    {

        var clients = from x in connection.TableauParentReports
                      .Include("TableauChildReports")
                      where x.ClientId == ClientID
                      select x;


    }



        throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

How to list everything if ClientID is there?

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't child reports always belong to the same client as the parent report? If so, you could remove `ClientId` from the child table. If not, you'd probably want a filtered `Include`, but that's not supported.

Comment: I don't get it. You need all parent and child reports that is associated to an specific client, right? If it so, your second query is doing the work... what is your problem? You are getting an error or something like that?

Comment: Thank you for your insight. I am testing it right now and will get back to you. Thank you!